# Django - AJAX - how to submit multiple forms?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

Here are my two ajax codes for two forms. These two codes are exactly the same, except for button `ID`

```
$("#form_1_submit").on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    var data = form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        dataType:"json",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            alert('ajax request')
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error")
        }

    });

    console.log(form.html())

});
$("#form_1_submit").on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    var data = form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        dataType:"json",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            alert('ajax request')
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error")
        }

    });

    console.log(form.html())

});
```

And here is my **views.py**:

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = Different_Model
    fields = '__all__'

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print(self.request.POST)


        form_1 = Form_2(request.POST, instance=Model_1.objects.filter(#some_filtering...)
        form_2 = Form_1(request.POST, instance=Model_2.objects.filter(#some_filtering...)

        if form_1.is_valid():
            form_1.save()
            return super().post(request, **kwargs)

        if form_2.is_valid():
            form_1.save()
            return super().post(request, **kwargs)

    return super().post(request, **kwargs)
```

There are two problems:

**First**: `$.axax({...})` gives `error`, instead of `success`, and I don't know why. But it still saves to DB.

**Second**: Submitting one form results in the other form's values not saving to DB. This is my current page:

[image]

Ideally, clicking one of the `Save` button should result in saving data to each respective tables in DB. But if I click `Save` for `Overall BHA`, it saves

```
{'bha_name': 'form_1', 'depth_in' : 'form_1', 'depth_out': 'form_1'},
```

but at the same time saves this to my DB's table for `Drill Bit`:

```
{'bit_type': '', 'size': '', 'bit_model': ''}
```

emptying out the stored values for the table.

why this is happening, and how do I fix it?

++ `form_1.is_valid()` always returns `True`. I think this is why `form_2`'s values are empty.

Comment: Your javascript is submitting only form one. The second function is only submitting form 1. Your code returns the response when form_1 is valid. The form_2 validation will not fire. You should just run these functions and not return the response immediately after each is saved. Also your form_2.is_valid() is saving form 1 and not form 2

Answer (score 0):

You could render several forms inside a single `HTML` form element and submit them all together without `ajax`

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm">{{ form_a.as_p }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm">{{ form_b.as_p }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm">{{ form_c.as_p }}</div>
</div>
 <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```